# JavaScript Liquid Handling Robot

Tags: javascript, robotics

I have the following code  (Using https://www.w3schools.com/js/  Because i don't know how else to test it)

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var a,b,c,d,e,text = "",x,y;
a = 25
b = Math.floor( a / 8 )
c = a - ( b * 8)
if (c == 0)
c = 8;
d = Math.ceil ( a / 8 )
e = 8
for (y = 1; y <= d; y++) {
    for (x = 1; x <= e; x++) {
    text += "<br>" + x + "," + y;
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

I was hoping that when **var a** (user input) was set to any number between 1 and 96 it would give all the coordinates from 1,1 to that number of well (on a 96 well plate A1 to H12.

eg. var a = 25 would give 1,1 2,1 3,1 4,1 5,1 6,1 7,1 8,1 1,2 2,2 3,2 4,2 5,2 6,2 7,2 8,2 1,3 2,3 3,3 4,3 5,3 6,3 7,3 8,3 1,4 and stop. Instead it finishes off the rest of the column 2,4 3,4 4,4 5,4 6,4 7,4 8,4 and then stops.

How do I get it to stop in the right place??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works, hope it helps!

```js
var text = "", start = 8, end = 25;

for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    text += "<br>" + ((i % 8) + 1) + "," + (Math.floor(i / 8) + 1)
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This (Math.floor(i / 8) + 1) + "," + ((i % 8) + 1) was the wrong way round but it worked like a charm. It was easy to change round. I don't get the modulus bit at all, I'll have to read up on that. Cheers

Comment: Is there a way to make this code start from 1,2 or 2,1??

Comment: Code updated, you can change the value of `start` and `end`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks.